# Locking fields in ArcGIS to maintain integrity of last_edited_user field

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, sql-server, arcgis-collector

I have a Collector for ArcGIS application which records the last_edited_user from the field, however post-processing needs to occur and overwrites my users from the field to my desktop user.  Is there a way to lock the last_edited_user to maintain my initial edited user?  I am using ArcGIS For Server 10.2.1 and SQL Server Database 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for this is to disable editor tracking and enable it.  I am using a Python script to automate my post processing of the data, so disable editor tracking will be at the beginning of the script while enable editor tracking will be at the end of the script.